# PHP & MySQL query date time stamp between

Tags: php, mysql

I am attempting to query for a record. The date is stored as a date time stamp and my query looks like this:

```
SELECT    count(c.id) as totalOrders
FROM      Cart c
WHERE     c.artist_id = 1
AND       c.paid = 1
AND       date_format(c.created, 'Y-m-d') between '2016-09-06' AND '2016-09-07'
```

My date time stamp is this: 2016-09-07 21:04:46

For some reason this does not return any records, why?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the following line:

```
AND date_format(c.created, 'Y-m-d') between '2016-09-06' AND '2016-09-07'
```

to

```
AND date(created) between '2016-09-06' AND '2016-09-07'
```

date() function will return the date from datetime and it will check in the given range.

Comment: But it will produce minor errors at the start and of the range. This is the accepted answer, but it's really not the best solution

Answer (score 1):

use date() function instead of date_format()

```
SELECT    count(c.id) as totalOrders
    FROM      Cart c
    WHERE     c.artist_id = 1
    AND       c.paid = 1
    AND       date(c.created) between '2016-09-06' AND '2016-09-07'
```

Comment: please describe the difference between code. and put some description on that answer. where they made mistake.